# New software centre won't run after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, software-center

The new "software centre" won't run after my upgrade to 16.04 last night. Trying it from the unity bar - nothing happens.  I read that it should be running gnome's software manager.  Trying from the command line - if I got the command right, gives this result

```
    $ gnome-software

(gnome-software:5748): Gs-WARNING **: failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Timeout was reached
```

Comment: Temprarily turn off automatic updates and then Try doing a sudo apt update in the terminal.   I had this happen.

Comment: Yep, it's working now.  How strange, but thanks...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after a fresh install and it started working after I killed the process in System Monitor.

Comment: Yes, some sort of problem here definitely.  Not sure it's much of an improvement to the old one anyway.

Comment: This. `ps -Af | grep gnome-software` then `kill <pid>`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I installed all the updates under <kbd>System Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Details</kbd> -> <kbd>Overview</kbd> -> <kbd>Install Updates</kbd> (Button in the bottom right corner. Ignore if it says System Up-To-Date) and rebooted my PC 3 times (ie: install updates then reboot, install updates then reboot, install updates then reboot, this was straight after a fresh install). Then finally the Software Centre began to work.