# Ubuntu 16.04 : Gnome Ubuntu Software Doesn't Open At All

Tags: 16.04, software-center, gnome-software

**Expected :** When I click on Ubuntu Software icon in taskbar or dash, it should open the software center.

**Actual :** The loading cursor comes in for few seconds and nothing happens. No window. Nothing.

A process for `gnome-software` is found in System Monitor though.

**Tried :** Re-installing `gnome-software-common`. Doesn't solve the issue.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gnome-software-common
```

Help?

**EDIT :**

Running `gnome-software` from terminal shows following output.

```
(gnome-software:11311): Gs-WARNING **: failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found out that it was indeed reported but no solution to those reports too.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573453
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321664
- [New software centre won't run after 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760953/new-software-centre-wont-run-after-16-04-upgrade)

Comment: Try running `gnome-software` in a Terminal an edit post with the output.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju - Updated.

Comment: The fix has been released! ([see last comment here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573052)) Update through `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: Did that. No change whatsoever. Still doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can install the classic 'Package Manager' : `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

If no visible launcher, please start synaptic with : `synaptic-pkexec`