# After installing Ubuntu 16.04 with the "erase disk" option three partitions show

Tags: software-installation, partitioning

As the tile says, I did a fresh install from a USB (LiveRecoveryCD). Now my system boots up with three mounted volumes (499 Mb, 10Gb, 10 Gb). Is this an issue? I did not create them when installing.
Whenever booting up I get a "System error prompt" but everything seems to work alright.
However I can't open the Ubuntu Software center.
Any command I could use to diagnose/fix this issues?
Thanks.

[image: Gparted screenshot]

Very odd: seems as if everything from my system is scattered through the different partitions!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After running `lsblk` [I got this output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23580976/).

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot from Gparted?

Comment: Your software center question has been asked and answered: http://askubuntu.com/questions/781255/software-center-wont-open-at-all and http://askubuntu.com/questions/780793/ubuntu-16-04-gnome-ubuntu-software-doesnt-open-at-all

Comment: @ElderGeek that fixed the Software Center, thanks.

Comment: @AndroidDev screenshot added

Comment: @AndroidDev any pointers?

Comment: I honestly don't know why you have so many partitions if you didn't create them manually during the installation. You selected "erase disk and install Ubuntu"?

Comment: @AndroidDev yes "erase disk and install Ubuntu" was the option. Since this is a fresh install, I don't have my files in the computer, so I can erase partitions without worrying about that.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in EFI or Legacy BIOS MBR mode?

Comment: @AndroidDev as per the instructions found here [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_the_computer_boots_the_Ubuntu_DVD_in_UEFI_mode] I got ' [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"
Legacy boot on HDD'

Comment: Hmmmm... That's very strange. I thought that maybe EFI was responsible *(I **HATE** EFI BTW)* but since it reported Legacy mode, something else must be the culprit. I'll post this question in the chatroom, where there are many very knowledgeable users who might be able to shed some light here...

Comment: @AndroidDev aprreciate that

Comment: @AndroidDev I just want to remove them, not necessarily find the cause. How do I remove them? are there any issues  in doing so?

Comment: @AndroidDev hello?

Comment: @Ghostsinmymachine - I would not delete them until we know what they are for. What kind of things are in them?

Comment: @AndroidDev attached screenshots

Comment: Can you please post the output of this command: `lsblk`

Comment: @AndroidDev output added

Comment: @AndroidDev output in my edited answer, that is [http://paste.ubuntu.com/23580976/]

Comment: Something strange is going on here. I'll see if I can do some research for you.

Comment: @AndroidDev ` I'll see if I can do some research for you.` sounds encouraging.  `Something strange is going on here.`... not that much Thanks for your help

Comment: Honestly, I'd just suggest you clean install with manual partitioning.

Comment: @AndroidDev got a link for that?

Comment: Follow this guide. **Only create the root and swap partitions.** http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: @chai-t-rex would you recommend the same? reinstall is the only way? out of curiosity, what happens if I keep the partitions?