# Software Center won't open at all

Tags: software-center

I am a new user of Ubuntu and I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version. My problem is that I can not open **software center**. It can open before. After updating and installing some applications, can't open the software center.

Comment: Run in terminal `sudo apt-get update`. Do you get any warning for broken packages or any errors?

Comment: Run in Terminal `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and show the output. 
Maybe some line incorrect

Comment: no error during update. it fine. when I click software center, it show in launcher, and disappear after a few second.

Comment: simply reinstall http://askubuntu.com/a/133473/464430

Comment: @NyeinChan, Try running it in terminal: `software-center` . Then [edit] the question and add the error message.

Comment: see this --> http://askubuntu.com/questions/760953/new-software-centre-wont-run-after-16-04-upgrade

Comment: apt install gnome-software

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing this same problem; I followed these steps to fixed it:-

**To uninstall Software Center:**

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
sudo apt-get autoremove software-center
```

**To re-install Software Center:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Thank you Mohamed Slama for [askubuntu.com/a/133473/464430](https://askubuntu.com/a/133473/464430)

Comment: autoremove doesn't require a package name.  Default action is to scan the whole system like update does.

Comment: I wonder what it's called in 16.04

Comment: I wonder what it's called in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. It's not called software-center.

Comment: Package 'software-center' is not installed, so not removed

Comment: it's no longer software-center. it's gnome-software

Answer (score 3):

Similar problem happened to me after I installed 16.04.1 LTS and updated software with Software Updater in it. When I tried to install new software from `*.deb` file, the Ubuntu Software opened and then exited quickly. I found the answer here. Actually I just tried to

> sudo apt-get update

in terminal. Then Ubuntu Software worked. I don't know why.

Comment: Updating to 16.04 has never worked for me.  Much better is to just stick with 14.04 because it is more mature.  Lots more people have posted helpful tips about it.  Debugging 16.04 is much more difficult, imho.

Answer (score 3):

Rename or remove the ~/.local/share/gnome-software. In the steps below it's removed and will be recreated when you start gnome-software. It currently has a list of what has been installed.

The first line will ensure the locked up instances are removed from memory. It might not be necessary.

```
$ killall gnome-software
$ rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software
```

Then it should enable to open software-center from dash or with `gnome-software` from terminal.

Ref: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825892/gnome-software-center-not-loading)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install the candidate version. It worked for me.

First, remove the snap-store. It also removes your Software Center.

```
snap remove snap-store
```

then install the candidate version

```
snap install snap-store --candidate
```

[image]

or, you can use another alternative, Gnome Software

```
sudo apt install gnome-software
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. the first suggestion minus the candidate version did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the software center is not installed. Try to install it manually:

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

Comment: I am also facing same problem.  I have tried following commands;
1. sudo apt-get update.
2. sudo apt install software-center
However the issue still persist. 
Software Center was working fine. It means it was installed and due some reason not working now.

Comment: Try removing it first then update then install it.

Comment: Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.