# Gnome Software Center Not Loading

Tags: gnome-software

After installing Ubuntu 16.04, the Gnome Software Center was working.  I then started to have issues with it freezing.  I decided to uninstall it through the terminal, and then reinstall it through the terminal.  If I try to open the software through Unity, the icon opens, but after a time disappears.  If I type in gnome-software in the terminal, the command just hangs until I kill it.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling using various commands I've found on this forum and others, but nothing will successfully reinstall the software.  All other software seems to be working fine.

Can anyone help?  Thank you.

Comment: The resolution might be the same.  However, the description of this issue and the one marked as duplicate is different.  The other one doesn't freeze.  It actually gives an error message.  This issue with gnome-software, there's not error message... nothing.  The system just hangs and will not feedback.  The terminal stays hung until you kill the process.

Comment: L.D. James is correct.  There are no error messages displayed.  I tried any and all solutions I previously found related to this topic before creating a new one.

Comment: @cmsrw If you had tried answers from a particular question on this site, you should write in your post explicitly what those answers and question are. How else are we supposed to know exactly what you have tried?

Comment: @L.D.James Okay, noted. I voted to reopen this question based on your comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is more than one Software "Center".  I'm seeing that some people have problems with certain ones.  Since you say Gnome Software Center isn't working for you, then you can install `ubuntu-software-center`.  You can do this by running these commands from the terminal.

*(Please note, the **$** symbol is the terminal prompt.  The command is what following the prompt.)*

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-software
```

You can decide which one will be your default by right clicking on a `*.deb` package and choosing the one that works best.  Then click on `Set as Default`.

**Note:**
`ubuntu-software` and `gnome-software` are the same on Ubuntu 16.04.  `ubuntu-software` is a symbolic link to `gnome-software`.  If one is broken it's unlikely the other will work.

The system updates above may resolve the issue.  If they don't, install an alternate software installer:

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-center
```

---

**Perform these steps to fix `gnome-software`/`ubuntu-software`**

Rename or remove the `~/.local/share/gnome-software`.  In the steps below it's removed and will be recreated when you start `gnome-software`.  It currently has a list of what has been installed.

The first line will ensure the locked up instances are removed from memory.  It might not be necessary.

```
$ killall gnome-software
$ rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software
```

Now run `ubuntu-software` or `gnome-software` from the Unity Launch Button.

Comment: This does not work.  I received the following error message after running the command on the third line: Unable to locate package ubuntu-software-center.  I am wanting back the same software center that originally came with Ubuntu 16.04.  Thank you.

Comment: @cmsrw I'll correct the typo.  I was thinking `software center` the way it looks in the dash.  However, leave the `center` off.  The package name is `ubuntu-software`.

Comment: Okay, I typed in the proper package name for the install.  No errors come up during the install. Yet, I still can't open it.  I've tried typing both ubuntu-software and gnome-software in the terminal, and it just hangs as before.

Comment: The older software-center does work - but i'd really like to get the one that came with 16.04 working again as it should.

Comment: @cmsrw Look at the new section in the answer, `fix gnome-software`.

Comment: Upon running the rm command, it returns the following message: "cannot remove '(local computer)/.local/share/gnome-software': Is a directory", and then returns me to the command line prompt.

Comment: @cmsrw Sorry.  I correct the command.  I left off the`-r` which will remove the directory.

Comment: Okay, that seemed to finally  fix it.  Sorry for all the difficulties.

Comment: @cmsrw It's not problem.  It's a pleasure.  You might consider clicking the checkmark on the answer so that others can see a workable solution.  This problem is discussed all over the Internet, with many people trying to find a solution that works.  Those two lines can probably save people lots of grief.

Comment: Have done.  Thank you for helping me solve this.  It is much appreciated.

Comment: `rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software ` worked for me like a charm! thx