# booting from cd while running ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, reboot

Hey I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 but I have a live CD which lets me play with a 32 bit architecture. But when I turn on and press <kbd>F12</kbd>it doesn't give me the option boot from CD, also I'm having some faults like my software center doesn't open so I'll probably want to reboot this Ubuntu too. Any suggestions? I don't have a lot of IT experience

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu on your computer?  Or are you saying you are just using the `Try Ubuntu` feature of the CD only?

Comment: Yh I installed it a while ago but I have a cd with a specially designed os to paractice, basically Im just asking how you boot from a cd once uv installed ubuntu

Comment: What is the model and make of your computer?

Comment: Lenovo G50-80, Model name is 80E5

Comment: The way you boot a CD/DVD is not dependent on the installed OS, if any. Either change the boot order at BIOS/UEFI or use the one-time boot menu if available. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu and an installer/live session is to be booted and run as is, it cannot run from an already installed OS.

Answer (score 1):

**Booting to CD on the Lenovo G50-80**

The installed OS (in this case Ubuntu) won't affect booting to the CD.  This is a function of the BIOS that happens before loading the OS.

This are steps from the **[Lenovo Forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/Lenovo-G50-80-Problem-with-Installing-Windows-8-from-CD/m-p/2185400#M48420)** for booting to the CD/DVD, and [Entering Lenovo G5-80 Bios Setup (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8zaFeBqg1U).  There is more than one method.  You may have performed a different method when you booted to the DVD to install Ubuntu.

It appears there is a `Lenova Key` on the left side of the Tablet to go into the boot menu.  The Youtube video shows the option for Selecting to make the Pendrive a bootable option.  You can use this as variants for selecting to boot to the DVD.  Further details can come from browsing the boot options you see while in the BIOS, along with Manufacturer's support.

**Software Center Issues**

Reinstalling Ubuntu might not be the best resolution.  Whatever problem you're having could come back to the new install.  You might best work with resolving the issue.

There are frequent glitches with the new Ubuntu Default Software Center.  I have experienced it on a number of installs.  On each occasion it was resolved with this commandline:

```
$ rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software
```

Other details of the issues with the Software center can be found at: [Gnome Software Center Not Loading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825892/gnome-software-center-not-loading/825907#825907)