# Gnome-software center partially loading

Tags: gnome-software

Gnome-Software in Ubuntu 16.04 is partially loading, and I can't install software and only appears the core package in software installed, and I can only find the software of the core packages.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

[image: Ubuntu Software window with nothing much showing up]

Comment: you can try [gnome-software-center-not-loading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/825892/gnome-software-center-not-loading)  at the bottom it has a way to repair it .. but .. I do prefer synaptic

Comment: restart your pc and try again.

Comment: Use software-center instead. See [my answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/985349/225694)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for it.

Try normal fully-functional software manager such one of

- Synaptic (`sudo apt-get install synaptic apt-xapian-index`)
- Muon (`sudo apt-get install muon`)

You can enter this [discussion on community.ubuntu.com](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/software-installation-on-modern-ubuntu/2555?u=norbert) about modern state of software installation.

Answer (score 0):

Another currently functional option for Ubuntu 16.04 is the tried and true Software Center:
[image: Software Center]

`sudo apt install software-center` to install (Note the absence of gnome in the package name. I've been using it on 16.04 since it's release and I've not had any issues with it. gnome-software-center is too buggy for my tastes. I still have it installed, but never use it.