# I have issues regarding Software Center on Ubuntu 16.04, it wont work when reinstalled

Tags: software-center

I recently looked up how to update and reinstall the software center after it had vanished off my netbook, i followed the instructions found here - [Software Center won't open at all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781255/software-center-wont-open-at-all?newreg=6e6eab1807b447a7b7832d5778c9bc4f) 
which was just a case of using
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center 
(it all seemed to go well) and now when I run it I get this chunk displayed through the terminal:

```
~$ software-center
/usr/bin/software-center:25: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/purchaseview.py:29: PyGIWarning: WebKit2 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import WebKit2 as webkit
2017-04-01 10:14:30,130 - softwarecenter.backend.zeitgeist_logger - WARNING - Support for Zeitgeist disabled
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/symbolic_icons.py:23: PyGIWarning: PangoCairo was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib, PangoCairo
2017-04-01 10:14:30,874 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2017-04-01 10:14:41,220 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2017-04-01 10:14:41,340 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2017-04-01 10:14:41,918 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2017-04-01 10:14:46,776 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - failed to load file /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
2017-04-01 10:15:14,597 - softwarecenter.db.utils - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:585: Warning: Source ID 71 was not found when attempting to remove it
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:585: Warning: g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:585: Warning: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:585: Warning: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:585: Warning: g_variant_builder_add_value: assertion '!GVSB(builder)->expected_type || g_variant_is_of_type (value, GVSB(builder)->expected_type)' failed
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:585: Warning: g_variant_builder_end: assertion 'GVSB(builder)->offset >= GVSB(builder)->min_items' failed
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:585: Warning: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
  return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1091, in on_menuitem_view_all_activate
    if self.menuitem_view.blocked:
AttributeError: 'MenuItem' object has no attribute 'blocked'
```

Does anyone have any idea what i need to do to get my system running and stable please? I've never been that good at understanding this and would appreciate any help anyone could give me. Pulling my hair out while quietly sobbing doesn't seem to be helping the problem.

Comment: added more info as requested :)