# E: Unable to locate package v4l-utils

Tags: update-manager

I want to install `v4l-utils`, actually, I'm Using `L4T` on `TX2`.

A few days ago, I updated `L4T` version `27.1` -> `28.1`.

And then I couln't open `System Settings -> Software & Updates`.

Anyway, I ran `sudo apt-get install v4l-utils` but an error occurred:

```
E: Unable to locate package v4l-utils.
```

I tried to find other articles like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt/378565#378565) in order to fix this, but my case seems a little different.

In conclusion, I have two problems.

1. I can't install `v4l-utils`.
2. I can't open `Software & Updates`.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on?  Do you have the 'universe' repository enabled?  (a quick scan showed 'v4l-utils' in universe for supported [trusty, xenial, artful] Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

If you search for `v4l-utils` in [this website](https://packages.ubuntu.com), you will see that it is only available for the following versions of Ubuntu in the `universe` repository:

- 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)
- 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)
- 17.04 (Zesty Zapus)
- 17.10 (Artful Aardvark)
- 18.04 (Bionic)

If you don't know which version of Ubuntu you're using, please execute the following command:

```
galoget@hackem:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS"
```

In the output of this command you can verify if you're using one of the releases mentioned before.

If you have one of them, please execute these commands and tell us if it worked.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install v4l-utils
```

Or download the `.DEB` file with its dependencies from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=v4l-utils&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) depending on your release.

If this doesn't work, please refer to the following steps to install the package from source:

1. Download the package from its [official website](https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-utils/), I tested this with `v4l-utils-1.14.1.tar.bz2`.
2. Extract the content with: `tar -xvjf v4l-utils-1.14.1.tar.bz2`
3. Check `README` and `INSTALL` files to verify dependencies and follow their instructions:

   ```
   $ ./bootstrap.sh
   $ ./configure
   $ make
   $ sudo make install
   ```

And about your 2nd issue, please refer to [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781255/software-center-wont-open-at-all), good luck.

Hope it helps.