# Ubuntu Software (Software centre) is not working

Tags: software-center

After latest update of Ubuntu 20.4, Ubuntu Software is not initialized to work and unable to get any software.

Comment: Please give more details to what the problem is. What exactly do you mean with "not inititialzed to work"? Also you could run the software center from the command line to check for errrors. First check the name of the programme with `snap list` then run `snap run name-of-package`. If you notice any errrors edit your question to include them.

Comment: [Software center wont open](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781255/software-center-wont-open-at-all) This may help you.